# Hive CSV cannot be imported in Pandas

Tags: csv, hive, beeline

I am dumping some Hive output into a csv using the pretty standard:

```
beeline -f my_script.hql --output_format=csv2 > data.csv
```

However this file does not seem to be proper CSV:

1. It cannot be read by unix systems

```
$ file data.csv
data.csv   data
```

2. It cannot be read by `pandas` in `python`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv("data.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/estergiadis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Users/estergiadis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 463, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/Users/estergiadis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1154, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/Users/estergiadis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2059, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 881, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 896, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 950, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 937, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2132, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 3, saw 7
```

The problem seems related to the quoting character (which is not `"` as in standard CSV).
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive uses \0 symbol as quotation symbol, you can replace it on '"'.

For example:

`cat data.csv | sed 's/"/""/g' | tr '\0' '"' > fixed_data.csv`